# Identify what values in a list doesn't exist in a Table column using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a list `cities = ['Rome', 'Barcelona', 'Budapest', 'Ljubljana']`

Then,

I have a sqlalchemy model as follows -

```
class Fly(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'fly'

    pkid = Column('pkid', INTEGER(unsigned=True), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    city = Column('city', VARCHAR(45), unique=True, nullable=False)
    country = Column('country', VARCHAR(45))
    flight_no = Column('Flight', VARCHAR(45))
```

I need to check if ALL the values in given `cities` list exists in fly table or not using sqlalchemy. Return true only if ALL the cities exists in table. Even if a single city doesn't exist in table, I need to return false and list of cities that doesn't exist. How to do that? Any ideas/hints/suggestions? I'm using MYSQL

Comment: Which database? MySQL?

Comment: Yes I'm using MySQL database

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to create a (temporary) relation based on the given list and take the set difference between it and the cities from the fly table. In other words create a union of the values from the list<sup>1</sup>:

```
from sqlalchemy import union, select, literal

cities_union = union(*[select([literal(v)]) for v in cities])
```

Then take the difference:

```
sq = cities_union.select().except_(select([Fly.city]))
```

and check that no rows are left after the difference:

```
res = session.query(~exists(sq)).scalar()
```

For a list of cities lacking from fly table omit the (NOT) EXISTS:

```
res = session.execute(sq).fetchall()
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Other database vendors may offer alternative methods for producing relations from arrays, such as Postgresql and its `unnest()`.